# JavaScript - moving object to a new location

Tags: javascript

I'm writing simple "snake" game and I'm facing this issue:
every tame my snake hits the red circle (apple) , apple should be moved to a new location on the canvas. Right now new apple appears, but the old one does not disappear ( it should) , and also when there are more than 2 apples on the canvas they create a filled figure... it looks like this: ibb.co/nrYdLQ (also shouldn't happen).

The code responsible for moving an apple is this:

```
if (!this.objectCollide(myApple)) {
    this.segments.pop();
  } else {
    myApple = new block(Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.width),Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.height))
  };
```

and I have no idea why It's working like I described above, instead just moving an apple to a new location and removing old one.
Please help.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e1ga0fpm/

full JavaScript code:

```
var gameField = document.getElementById('gameField');
var ctx = gameField.getContext("2d");
var blockSize = 10;
columnCt = gameField.width / blockSize;
rowsCt = gameField.height / blockSize;

var block = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

block.prototype.drawBlock = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(this.x * blockSize, this.y * blockSize, blockSize,
    blockSize);
};

block.prototype.drawApple = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 6, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [new block(20, 20), new block(19, 20), new block(18, 20), new block(17, 20),
    new block(16, 20), new block(15, 20), new block(14, 20), new block(13, 20), new block(12, 20),
    new block(11, 20), new block(10, 20)
  ];
  this.direction = "right";
}

Snake.prototype.drawSnake = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawBlock();
  }
}

Snake.prototype.setDirection = function(dir) {
  if (this.direction == "left" && dir == "right" || this.direction == "right" && dir == "left" || this.direction == "up" && dir == "down" ||
    this.direction == "down" && dir == "up") {
    return
  } else {
    this.direction = dir;
  };
};

Snake.prototype.objectCollide = function(obj) {
  if (this.segments[0].x == Math.round(obj.x / blockSize) && this.segments[0].y == Math.round(obj.y / blockSize)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
};

Snake.prototype.move = function() {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;

  switch (this.direction) {
    case "right":
      newHead = new block(head.x + 1, head.y);
      break;
    case "left":
      newHead = new block(head.x - 1, head.y)
      break;
    case "down":
      newHead = new block(head.x, head.y + 1)
      break;
    case "up":
      newHead = new block(head.x, head.y - 1)
      break;
  }

  this.segments.unshift(newHead);

  if (!this.objectCollide(myApple)) {
    this.segments.pop();
  } else {
    myApple = new block(Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.width),Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.height))
  };
  var collision = newHead.x >= columnCt || newHead.x <= -1 ||
    newHead.y >= rowsCt || newHead.y <= -1;

  for (i = 1; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (this.segments[i].x == newHead.x && this.segments[i].y == newHead.y) {
      collision = true;
      break;
    };
  };

  if (collision) {
    clearInterval(myFun);
  };

};

var mySnake = new Snake()
mySnake.drawSnake();
var myApple = new block(Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.width),
  Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.height));
var myFun = setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, gameField.width, gameField.height);
  mySnake.move();
  mySnake.drawSnake();
  myApple.drawApple();
}, 100)

var directions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode]
  if (newDirection != undefined) {
    mySnake.setDirection(newDirection);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `beginpath` while you draw apple. Also when apple eaten, you have to add new block to snake. Check edited code below.

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1ga0fpm/2/)

```
block.prototype.drawApple = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 6, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```js
var gameField = document.getElementById('gameField');
var ctx = gameField.getContext("2d");
var blockSize = 10;
columnCt = gameField.width / blockSize;
rowsCt = gameField.height / blockSize;

var block = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

block.prototype.drawBlock = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(this.x * blockSize, this.y * blockSize, blockSize,
    blockSize);
};

block.prototype.drawApple = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 6, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();

}

var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [new block(20, 20), new block(19, 20), new block(18, 20), new block(17, 20),
    new block(16, 20), new block(15, 20)
  ];
  this.direction = "right";
}

Snake.prototype.drawSnake = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawBlock();
  }
}

Snake.prototype.setDirection = function(dir) {
  if (this.direction == "left" && dir == "right" || this.direction == "right" && dir == "left" || this.direction == "up" && dir == "down" ||
    this.direction == "down" && dir == "up") {
    return
  } else {
    this.direction = dir;
  };
};

Snake.prototype.objectCollide = function(obj) {
  if (this.segments[0].x == Math.round(obj.x / blockSize) && this.segments[0].y == Math.round(obj.y / blockSize)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
};

Snake.prototype.move = function() {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;

  switch (this.direction) {
    case "right":
      newHead = new block(head.x + 1, head.y);
      break;
    case "left":
      newHead = new block(head.x - 1, head.y)
      break;
    case "down":
      newHead = new block(head.x, head.y + 1)
      break;
    case "up":
      newHead = new block(head.x, head.y - 1)
      break;
  }

  this.segments.unshift(newHead);

  if (!this.objectCollide(myApple)) {
    this.segments.pop();
  } else {
    myApple = new block(Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.width), Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.height));
    this.segments.push(new block(this.segments[0][0], 20))
  };
  var collision = newHead.x >= columnCt || newHead.x <= -1 ||
    newHead.y >= rowsCt || newHead.y <= -1;

  for (i = 1; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (this.segments[i].x == newHead.x && this.segments[i].y == newHead.y) {
      collision = true;
      break;
    };
  };

  if (collision) {
    clearInterval(myFun);
  };

};

var mySnake = new Snake()
mySnake.drawSnake();
var myApple = new block(Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.width),
  Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.height));
var myFun = setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, gameField.width, gameField.height);
  mySnake.move();
  mySnake.drawSnake();
  myApple.drawApple();
}, 100)

var directions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode]
  if (newDirection != undefined) {
    mySnake.setDirection(newDirection);
  };
};
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameField" height="500" width="500">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you ! that works like a charm ! do you mind explaining a little bit how ctx.beginPath(); made it work? because it confuses me..

Comment: @Pawel Check updated code with when apple eaten, snake size also increase.

Comment: Thanks! but the snake size was also increasing before :)  I'n my previous code I simply did not call method `.pop()` on `snake.segments` when snake ate the apple, and that's how the size was increasing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite unsure why the apple is not "eaten" however, I might know why it looks so weird.

If you draw to a canvas it looks like a pen. So whenever you draw a new apple, the pen moves to that position, and draws a line. After a few apples, if you call .fill(), this (yet invisible) line, gets filled. So you need to move the pen before you draw:

```
block.prototype.drawApple = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
  ctx.moveTo(this.x,this.y);
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 6, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! , I really don't know why I did not think about that...     So 1 issue solved, but why the apple is not "eaten"?